# Including jar in classpath when running Gradle's PMD plugin

Tags: gradle, pmd

I'm attempting to run PMD with a custom rule set file, but that rule set includes a rule that's a custom class. This class exists in a jar that is *not* pulled in as a dependency, but instead comes in a zip file (which is a dependency) and gets unpacked. Imagine the PMD rule class is just in `build/extralib/blah.jar`.

How do I include that in my classpath when running PMD only? What I've tried, but didn't work:

```
pmd {
    ruleSetFiles = files("build/utils/pmd-rules.xml")
    pmdClasspath = files("build/extralib")
}
```

To be clear, the error is: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.package.for.pmd.CrazyRule`. This happens when running `pmdMain`.

Secondary question: what's the difference between [Pmd](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Pmd.html) and [PmdExtension](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html)? Pmd has `pmdClasspath`, but PmdExtension does not. When I added `pmdClasspath`, I got:

`Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "pmdClasspath" on "org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension_Decorated@70221fc5", value: "file collection".`

So I guess it only adheres to PmdExtension? As a Gradle newbie, it's a bit confusing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are configuring `pmd { ... }`, you are configuring the *extension*. Sometimes you may need to drop down to the task level and configure `tasks.pmd { ... }` instead. (Having an extension and a task of the same name is a common pattern used by the code quality and IDE extensions/tasks.) The easiest way to add stuff to the PMD class path is:

```
dependencies {
    pmd ...
}
```

I haven't tried if this works for adding external rules, but it might.

Comment: It seems to work. I have to manually add the PMD dependency, too, but that's OK. Thus, I have a dependency like: `pmd fileTree(dir: 'build/extralib', includes: ['*.jar'])` and `pmd 'pmd:pmd:4.3'`. I got rid of the `pmdClasspath`, too. Seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Hi can you expand your answer, I struck with same issue. Could  u please add your answer in details.

Comment: if I add dependencies as `pmd ...` I get error as `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.pmd.PMD` what can be wrong with it?